Оптимизация кода для увеличения FPS
Я писал редактор карт для моей игры.
Код:
from ursina import *

class Room:
    def __init__(self, tag):
        self.tag = tag
        self.position = Vec3(0, 0, 0)
        self.room_data = {}
        self.wall_entities = []
        self.floor_entities = []

    def load_room_data(self, data: dict):
        for entity in self.floor_entities:
            entity.disable()
            del entity
        
        for entity in self.wall_entities:
            entity.disable()
            del entity

        for floor_name in data["floors"]:
            floor = data["floors"][floor_name]
            pos = Vec3(floor[1], floor[2], floor[3])
            rot = Vec3(floor[4], floor[5], floor[6])
            scale = Vec3(floor[7], floor[8], floor[9])
            uvs_scale = Vec2(floor[7],floor[9])
            collider = floor[10]
            floor_entity = Entity(model='plane', texture='../textures/tilefloor.jpg',collider=collider)
            floor_entity.position = pos
            floor_entity.rotation = rot
            floor_entity.scale = scale
            floor_entity.uvs = uvs_scale
            self.floor_entities.append(floor_entity)

        for wall_name in data["walls"]:
            wall =  data["walls"][wall_name]
            pos = Vec3(wall[1], wall[2], wall[3])
            rot = Vec3(wall[4], wall[5], wall[6])
            scale = Vec3(wall[7], wall[8], wall[9])
            collider = wall[10]
            uvs_scale = Vec2(wall[7],wall[9])
            if wall[0] == "lite":
                wall_entity = Entity(model='quad', texture="../textures/whitewall.jpg")
            else:
                wall_entity = Entity(modle='quad',texture='../textures/error.png')
            wall_entity.position = pos
            wall_entity.rotation = rot
            wall_entity.scale = scale
            wall_entity.uvs = uvs_scale
            self.wall_entities.append(wall_entity)

        self.room_data = data

room_editor_app = Ursina()

room = Room('new_room')
room_data = {
    "floors": {},
    "walls": {},
    "props": {},
    "items": {}
}

def new_floor():
    room_data["floors"][id_enter.text] = ([None,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,'box'])

def new_wall():
    room_data["walls"][id_enter.text] = (['lite',0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,'box'])

def update():
    room.load_room_data(room_data)

def apply_settings():
    id = id_enter_for_settings.text
    pos = pos_entry.text
    rot = rot_entry.text
    scale = scale_entry.text
    if id.startswith('f'):
        positions = pos.split(',')
        rotations = rot.split(',')
        scales = scale.split(',')
        room_data["floors"][id[1:]] = ([None,float(positions[0]),float(positions[1]),float(positions[2]),float(rotations[0]),float(rotations[1]),float(rotations[2]),float(scales[0]),float(scales[1]),float(scales[2]),'box'])
    elif id.startswith('w'):
        positions = pos.split(',')
        rotations = rot.split(',')
        scales = scale.split(',')
        room_data["walls"][id[1:]] = (['lite',float(positions[0]),float(positions[1]),float(positions[2]),float(rotations[0]),float(rotations[1]),float(rotations[2]),float(scales[0]),float(scales[1]),float(scales[2]),'box'])

def delete_object():
    id = id_enter_for_settings.text
    if id.startswith('f'):
        del room_data["floors"][id[1:]]
    elif id.startswith('w'):
        del room_data["walls"][id[1:]]
camera = EditorCamera()

new_floor = Button(text='New floor',on_click=new_floor)
new_floor.scale = Vec2(0.1, 0.05)
new_floor.position=Vec2(-0.4, 0.4)
new_floor.text_size=1

new_wall = Button(text='New wall',on_click=new_wall)
new_wall.scale = Vec2(0.1, 0.05)
new_wall.position=Vec2(-0.4, 0.3)
new_wall.text_size=1

rot_entry_text = Text("ID to spawn object")
rot_entry_text.position = Vec2(-0.65, 0.25)

id_enter = InputField('')
id_enter.position = Vec2(-0.4, 0.2)
id_enter.scale = Vec2(0.5, 0.05)
id_enter.text_size=1

id_enter_for_settings_text = Text('ID for object to setting, example - fFloor1 or wWall1')
id_enter_for_settings_text.position = Vec2(0.25, 0.45)

id_enter_for_settings = InputField('')
id_enter_for_settings.position = Vec2(0.5, 0.4)
id_enter_for_settings.scale = Vec2(0.5, 0.05)
id_enter_for_settings.text_size=1

pos_entry_text = Text("Pos (x,y,z)")
pos_entry_text.position = Vec2(0.25, 0.35)

pos_entry = InputField('0,0,0')
pos_entry.position = Vec2(0.5, 0.3)
pos_entry.scale = Vec2(0.5, 0.05)
pos_entry.text_size=1

rot_entry_text = Text("Rot (x,y,z)")
rot_entry_text.position = Vec2(0.25, 0.25)

rot_entry = InputField('')
rot_entry.position = Vec2(0.5, 0.2)
rot_entry.scale = Vec2(0.5, 0.05)
rot_entry.text_size=1

scale_entry_text = Text("Scale (x,y,z)")
scale_entry_text.position = Vec2(0.25, 0.15)

scale_entry = InputField('')
scale_entry.position = Vec2(0.5, 0.1)
scale_entry.scale = Vec2(0.5, 0.05)
scale_entry.text_size=1

button_apply = Button(text='Apply settings',on_click=lambda:apply_settings())
button_apply.scale = Vec2(0.1, 0.05)
button_apply.position=Vec2(0.5, 0)
button_apply.text_size=1

button_apply = Button(text='Delete objects',on_click=lambda:delete_object())
button_apply.scale = Vec2(0.1, 0.05)
button_apply.position=Vec2(0.5, -0.1)
button_apply.text_size=1

room_editor_app.run()

Но я столкнулся с проблемой: дело в том, что падает FPS, причём с каждым разом всё меньше и меньше (причём постепенно и медленно).
Падание FPS появляется только после применения настроек (функция apply_settings). Скорее всего я что-то начудил в своём коде.
Подскажите, что не так?
